# Git branch always adds the files from other branch

Tags: git

Lets say I have a following git repo:

```
root\
    AAA\
    BBB\
    CCC\
```

I need to have 3 different branches for each of these directories + one master branch to have them all. The things I did:

```
git init
git remote add origin <my_repo_ssh_address>
git checkout -b AAA
git add AAA
git commit -m "Created AAA branch"
git push origin AAA
```

Now there is `AAA` branch on my repo and there is an `AAA` folder in it. Then I want to have `BBB` branch:

```
git checkout -b BBB
git add BBB
git commit -m "Created BBB branch"
git push origin BBB
```

If I do it, then I have two branches `AAA` and `BBB` but in the `BBB` branch I  have two directories `AAA` and `BBB`, but I want (actually I need) to have only `BBB` directory. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Git doesn't store empty directories, in your experiment did you have files in those directories? Also, what is your current branch when you type `git checkout -b BBB`. Is it AAA?

Comment: Yes I did. In every folder there's a file

Comment: You need yo use `git checkout --orphan BBB` otherwise it will take commits from parent also.

Comment: That's right! But then I have to `git rm --cached` the files which where commited on `AAA` branch, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full specification for the `git checkout -b` command is `git checkout -b <branch> [<start point>]`. The start point is optional and uses the current branch as the default.

Because you're first creating branch `AAA` and committing on it, I'm assuming `AAA` is still your current branch when you're creating `BBB`. This will result in the following commit graph after you've committed the new files:

```
-----                -----
| 1 |----------------| 2 | 
-----                -----
  ^                    ^
 AAA                  BBB
```

As you can see, the changes in branch `AAA` are included in branch `BBB`.

## How to create seperate branches

To have completely separate branches, you can use the `--orphan` option. The `--orphan` option will create a branch without a history. Executing `git checkout --orphan BBB` will create a new branch called `BBB` without including the files from your current branch `AAA`. It will result in the following commit graph after you've committed the new files:

```
-----
| 1 |
-----
  ^ 
 AAA

-----
| 2 |
-----
  ^ 
 BBB
```

The files of `AAA` will still be in your working directory though, so you will have to delete them from disk. Don't worry, the files from `AAA` are stored in git and you can get them back anytime by switching back to the `AAA` branch by executing `git checkout AAA`.

## Why separate unconnected branches?

Although there are use cases for having unconnected branches, generally you want branches to have a single point of origin within your history. If your goal is to have source control on multiple directories, it is recommended to have multiple git repositories, each have their commit history and branches.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone seems focused on using orphan branches to address this; which is one option, though probably not necessary and, given your stated requirements, it's going to cause you another minor problem.  Once I sort through that, though, I'm going to mention: your stated requirements are probably going to cause you a bigger problem, because this isn't what branches are for in git.

So let's begin.

So you started with an empty repository and your first commit was to the `AAA` branch with an `AAA/` directory in it.

Because that was your *first* commit, you can't go back to "before the `AAA` folder was added" to create the `BBB` branch and `BBB/` directory.  Hence peoples' suggestion to use an orphan branch, so that you go back to having no history at all.  And that will work, but you mentioned you want a `master` branch that will contain all three subdirectories.

Well, here's what's going to happen:  You'll create some commits.

```
A1 -- A2 -- A3 <--(AAA)

B1 -- B2 <--(BBB)
```

and then you'll want to create the master branch.  Perhaps you'll say

```
git checkout AAA
git checkout -b master
git merge BBB
```

and you'll get an error, because `BBB` has no common history with `AAA` (and now `master`).  It's not terribly hard to solve (`git merge` has an `--allow-unrelated-histories` option), but then again you can plan ahead and avoid it from the beginning by starting your repository in a different way.

```
git init
git commit --allow-empty
git checkout -b AAA
mkdir AAA
touch AAA/some-file
git add .
git commit
git checkout master
git checkout -b BBB
mkdir BBB
touch BBB/some-file
git add .
git commit
```

The first commit creates the `master` branch with no content.  Then each of the directory-specific branches is created from there.  So you create some commits

```
O <--(master)
|\
| A1 -- A2 -- A3 <--(AAA)
 \
  B1 -- B2 <--(BBB)
```

and then populate the `master` content

```
git checkout master
git merge AAA
git merge BBB
```

to get

```
O -------------- M1 ------- M2 <--(master)
|\              /          /
| A1 -- A2 -- A3 <--(AAA) /
 \                       /
  B1 ----------------- B2 <--(BBB)
```

This is just a little simpler.  Multi-root repos are fine when there's a reason to have them, but they aren't common and sometimes output from some commands may seem confusing if you're not used to this scenario.

And anyway, this approach doesn't arbitrarily single one of `AAA` or `BBB` out as the starting point for `master`; which again doesn't *really* matter, but I think is a little less ugly.

"A little less ugly", though, because as I note at the start, this isn't *really* what branches are for.  If you have three independent histories and just want to have the ability to pull coordinated versions of them together (in what you're calling `master`), the most straightforward solution is to have three repos (`AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC`) instead of three branches, and then maybe have a master repo that treats those 3 as submodules.